# How to save an ArrayList in Play?

Tags: java, arraylist, playframework-2.0, ebean

This might seem like a very basic question, but I have a model (User) which I want to store an ArrayList of Strings (they are the id's of other users). I declare the List like this:

```
 public List<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();
```

After I add an entry to the array, I save the user. But friends is always null when I try to use it. Is there a specific way to save an ArrayList? Any help would be appreciated.

My model:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

@Id
public String username;
public String password;

public List<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();

public static Finder<String, User> find = new Finder<String, User>(String.class, User.class);

// Constructor
public User(String username, String password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

// Methods
public void addFriend(String friend){
    friends.add(friend);
}

// Static Methods
public static User authenticate(String username, String password){
    return find.where().eq("username", username).eq("password", password).findUnique();
}

public static void befriend(String user1, String user2){
    User.find.ref(user1).addFriend(user2));
    User.find.ref(user2).addFriend(user1);

    User.find.ref(user1).save();
    User.find.ref(user2).save();
}
```

}

The controller method:

```
return ok(index.render(
        User.find.byId(request().username()).friends,
));
```

And a very simple view:

```
@(friends: List[User])

<div id="current_friends">
    @for(friend <- friends) {
        @friend.username
    }
</div>
```

Comment: There is no problem with your Arraylist declaration. Can you share the code to save into the arraylist and the way you are trying to retrieve.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I have edited my question to show more code. Are there any other parts of it that would be helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the relations 'manually' with `saveManyToManyAssociations(String fieldname)`, for an example:

```
public static void befriend(String userName1, String userName2){

    User user1 = User.find.byId(userName1);
    User user2 = User.find.byId(userName2);

    user1.friends.add(user2);
    user2.friends.add(user1);

    user1.save();
    user2.save();

    // here...
    user1.saveManyToManyAssociations("friends");
    user2.saveManyToManyAssociations("friends");

}
```

(note: written from top of my had so debug it yourself pls)

Answer (score 0):

One potential reason for this problem could be your view:

The first line of your view is

```
@(friends: List[User])
```

The User does not have a package name, which could cause the null pointer exception.
In my case, my User bean is under models package, so I have the following line:

```
@(friends: List[models.User])
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same problem, and here is how I fixed it (with a little explanation coming along).

In fact, you try to save an ArrayList (thus something which size is undefined) in a DataBase. And apparently (and quite logically), the Play Framework doesn't really like it ; you have to use whether annotations or a transient class. I decided to use the class way (also because i don't know how to use the annotations to make a sub table, so I didn't took the risk, but it's not the best way to do it. In fact, it's an horrible way of doing it. But still, here it is).

In your case, you could to this :

```
@Entity
public class Friends extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    @Required
    public String user1;
    @Required
    public String user2;

    public static Finder<Long, Friends> find = new Finder<Long, Friends>(Long.class, Friends.class);

    //Here put your functions, I myself only added an insert method for the moment :

    public static void add(String user1, String user2){
        Friends f = new Friends();
        f.user1 = user1;
        f.user2 = user2;
        bu.save();
    }
}
```

And in your User model, just change the part in which you save both user into each other's List by this function.

Hope this will help.

Note : the id is here because I like numeric ids, feel free to change it.

Note 2 : Of course, it would be much better to use @ManyToOne and @OneToMany annotations, but as I wrote before, I don't know exactly how does it work.